# PHP only removing specific words without affecting rest of the string

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to filter my title to remove the word "Tag:" inside and it is working fine, however when my following word starts with "T" it will instantly be removed as well.

This was how i've set my code

```
<?php $tag = "Tag: "; 
if( str_replace( $tag, "", $title) == true  ):
else:echo ltrim($title, $tag); 
endif ?>
```

so when my title is `Tag: Home` it will return `Home` just fine,
but if my title is something like `Tag: Teachers` it will return me `eachers` instead.
How do i make it so I can still display any title starting with T without it being removed.

Comment: Have a read what [`ltrim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) actually does, it's not what you think.

Comment: You can simply use `str_replace` function to remove what you don't want from your title

Comment: Yes, ltrim() looks upon characters and not characters as an individual word. If you know that `Tag:` **will** always exist in your string, just use `substr()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. it will returns only `Teacher`

```
 $str = "Tag: Teacher"; 

 $str = str_replace("Tag:", "", $str);
 echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following to remove the tag `Tag:`

```
<?php
$title = 'Tag: Teachers';
echo removeTag($title); // Teachers

function removeTag(string $str, string $tag = "Tag: "): string
{
   $str = str_replace($tag, "", $str);
   return $str;
}
```